# Equivalent of RxJS throttleTime in Rx.NET

Tags: system.reactive

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of RxJS [`throttleTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime) using Rx.NET (it's not implemented in .NET).

`throttleTime` emits a value from the source Observable, then ignores subsequent source values for duration milliseconds, then repeats this process.
This differs from `throttle` which waits a time before emitting. `throttleTime` emits the first item and then waits before emitting again.

Any pointers as to how to go about this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public static IObservable<T> ThrottleTime<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan ts)
{
    return ThrottleTime(source, ts, Scheduler.Default);
}

public static IObservable<T> ThrottleTime<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan ts, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source
        .Timestamp(scheduler)
        .Scan((EmitValue: false, OpenTime: DateTimeOffset.MinValue, Item: default(T)), (state, item) => item.Timestamp > state.OpenTime
            ? (true, item.Timestamp + ts, item.Value)
            : (false, state.OpenTime, item.Value)
        )
        .Where(t => t.EmitValue)
        .Select(t => t.Item);
}
```

Explanation: Think of `ThrottleTime` as having a single state variable: The next time the gate opens to a new value. If the source item is before this timed-gate value, then nothing happens. If the source item is after it, then pass it through, and reset the gate value to the latest timestamp.

`Scan` holds the time value in a tuple (the `OpenTime` variable). The other fields on the tuple are more helpful downstream.